# Get the string name of an enumeration or class without namespace?

Tags: c#, .net

So,
I'd like to get the name of an enumeration or class without the full namespace appended on to the front of it...  For example:

```
enum MyEnum {
    // enum values here
}

// somewhere else in the code
string testString = ????  // ???? returns "MyEnum"
```

`typeof(MyEnum)` mostly works, however the namespace of the enumeration is appended to the front.

Any help would be appreciated... thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`.Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.name(v=VS.100).aspx) to get only the type in the string, like this:

```
string testString = typeof(MyEnum).Name;
```

Here's some examples:

```
typeof(String).Name // "String"
typeof(String).FullName // "System.String"
```

[`.FullName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.fullname.aspx) like the example above gives the full type name, including the namespace.

Comment: Perfect thanks... I didn't know typeof() had so many nifty properties.  I didn't even think to check the intellisense for it haha.

Comment: @Polaris - When you're calling it you're getting a [`System.Type`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ek3kwtc.aspx) so anything you want to use it for :)

Comment: It should be pointed out that `typeof(Dictionary<string, string>).Name` returns `Dictionary'2` (but with a backtick instead of the apostrophe), and similarly for all other generic types.